# Project Euler #3 (C++)

Tags: c++

I wrote a code to solve this question and I was wondering if it was efficient or not. I just started learning code last week and I would like to get some input so I can get in the habit of writing the most efficient code possible.
The question is :

What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


// What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?
int main()
{
    long long greaterFactor = 600851475143;

    for (long long i = 3; i <= greaterFactor; i += 2)
    {
        if (greaterFactor % i == 0)                 // checks if i is a factor
        {
            if (greaterFactor / i >= i)             // if the other factor (not i) of greaterFactor is greater or equal (for squared numbers)
            {
                greaterFactor /= i;                 // greaterFactor becomes the other factor
                i -= 2;                             // in case prime factor shows up more than 1 time (eg - > 11 * 11 * 17 -> 11 & 11 * 17 -> 11 & 11 & 17
            }                                       // then continues to check next integers to completely factor smaller factors until greaterFactor has no more factors
        }
    }

    cout << "The largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 is:\n" << greaterFactor << endl;
    return 0;
}   // end main()
```

Comment: If the code works the question is more suited for the [codereview.se] site.

Comment: That brute-force thing is the least efficient method of all. But ... while there are some better methods (which are more complicated), none of them is really fast. Factorization is NP-hard. For a 1-week-coder, the solution is fine.

Comment: Please make sure you include the problem's descrition in your post, CR needs to know *what you're trying to accomplish* in order to tell you if you're *doing it right* =)

Comment: Ahh my bad. It was in a comment in my code, but I forgot to put it in the description.

Comment: @GaryFeng Keep in mind that they will give feedback regarding your code style/quality/whatever, but they won´t be very interested in the algorithmic part. If you want to learn about faster algos (after recherching yourself first a bit), the CompSci or Math sibling sites may be more suitable (or Cryptography...)

Comment: @deviantfan [uh-huh. and where's your Code Review account?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/73370/23788)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I don´t have one, but I´m reading regularely there (for whatever reason). And what do you want to say with the link? I see code performance improvements, but nothing about different algorithmic approaches.

Comment: @deviantfan, improving your algorithm is an on-topic post on Code Review, so long as it contains working code, demonstrating that algorithm. If your query is purely algorithmic, Math.SE *may* be the site for you, however, I am unfamiliar with their on-topic policies.

Comment: @deviantfan You'd be a most welcome reviewer then! Hop aboard, share your knowledge! We need more answerers like you! That link only meant to say "nope. not just code style/quality/whatever." - but yeah, people (including myself) will usually pick on the "easy" in-your-face stuff first. If you submit code for review that's poorly indented, with poor naming and no apparent coding style convention, odds are you'll get feedback on that before anything else. Someone that doesn't want that kind of feedback should post a question with their cleanest code, without those blatant issues.

Comment: it should be `600851475143LL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an inefficiency in your algorithm. You don't do the division if the "other" divisor is bigger. That's a BIG mistake. Always do the division as that will reduce the number. By taking the divisors out in order from lowest to highest, each will be prime. The last one you find is the highest.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long long i, n = 600851475143;
    for (i = 3; n > 1; i += 2)
        while (n % i == 0)
            n /= i;
    printf("%lld\n", i - 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation along with an example :)

Answer (score 1):

After running your code against some test cases. This is what I found.

> If you take the value of **greaterFactor** as ***2^n***  i.e (16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, ...so on). It fails to execute. And the algorithm you have used is very *inefficient*.

Now, let's talk about the correct and efficient algorithm:

> Here, I'm considering the Problem : Project Euler 3 as described in this [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler003) of Hackerrank Domain. Please, go through the link and check the constraints before reading further.

As Problem says that the maximum value of **N** (or your greaterFactor) could be ***10^12***. And, suppose you are given a value of **N** as 199,815,106,433 which is the 8,000,000,000th prime number. Now, think how would you sort this problem out with your algorithm, whose time complexity is O(n) .

Now, look at this code snippet:

```
long long N, temp_N, i;
cin>>N;
temp_N = N;

for(i=2; i*i <= N; i++) {
    if(N%i == 0) {
        while(N%i == 0) {
            N /= i;
        }
    }
}

if(N != 1) {
    cout<<N<<endl;
} else {
    cout<<i-1<<endl;
}
```

This code has the time complexity of O(sqrt(n)) and is efficient to calculate the desired output for **all the values of num** greater than **1**.

**Note:** The above code could even work fine for the values of **N** in the range of **[2, 10^18]**.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost on the right track. Here is alternative solution. It is fast (might not be the fastest)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long long i;
    long long n = 600851475143;

    for(i = 3; i <= n; i += 2) {
        while(n % i == 0) {
            n /= i;
        }

        if (n == 1) break;
    }

    std::cout << "Largest prime factor " << i;
}
```

Comment: I don´t see much relevant difference.

Comment: @deviantfan, there is different. For example: 63 = 3 * 3 * 7. In his code, he will divide 63 by 3 only one time.

Comment: Did you see the `i -= 2;` in the question? (and the comment explains why it is there).

Comment: yes, I actually thought about that and added it in xD.
I am a bit curious as to which one of these would be considered "better code" though. I didn't think about using a while loop to eliminate the need for my i -= 2;.

Comment: then, it is still less efficient because you use extra minus and extra division on each loop. Haha

Comment: Noted that, this algorithm is not a brute force. At worst case, it runs O(sqrt(n)) times. On average, it will run faster than that.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution in c++ would be:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
    {
    long long num=600851475143;
    int i=2,res;

    for(i=2;i<(num/2);i++)
    {
        if(!(num%i) && num>0)
        {
            num=num/i;      
    }
    }
    std::cout<<" Biggest LCM is ="<<num;
    return 0;
}
```